# Talend - Custom join component

Tags: java, talend

My current use case is the following:

```
TABEL1 
A   | B     | time  
12  | 13    |20161012132401

TABEL2  
A   | B     | time 
12  | 13    |20161012132403 
12  | 13    |20161012132402
```

I want to do a join based on A and B. But from those matches, I only want to join the one with the time from tabel2 closest to tabel1.

Therefore I want to develop a custom component in Talend (documentation is almost non-existent). 
The main problem I have currently is that the logic is a double loop. I need the check each row from tabel1 to the rows of tabel2. (and the javajet runs the code for each row and goes to the next one, there seems to be no persistence beside *globalmap*)

How do you get the complete List of rows from tabel2 before you run the rows from tabel1?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? Couldn't you join on minute granularity?

Comment: As in, the second row of tabel2 is closer to the row of tabel1 (the time column). So I only want to join those two rows.

Comment: Is creating a new component your requirement ? Or a solution with basic component would be acceptable ?

Comment: Creating a new component is a requirement. It is my use case on how to properly implement components in Talend :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a new component for this case. While fetching data from Table2, use below sql query

```
select A, B, MIN(time) AS time GROUP BY A, B.
```

Now you will get records as below for Table2,

A   | B     | time
12  | 13    |20161012132402

Hope this should solve your problem.

Comment: As said in the comments, making a new component is a requirement :)